# Stability of differential system when eigenvalue is zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I'm trying to figure out the stability of the origin $O(0,0)$ for the following system of differential equations :
$$x'= -x^2 + 2xy$$
$$y'=-2y+y^2+xy$$
using the following method/theorem/lemma which I found in my notes (it's the only thing that is mentioned about systems which yield an eigenvalue equal to zero) :

> **Zero Eigenvalue : Stability**
>
> Let $f=(f_1,f_2) : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, where $f\in C^k(\mathbb R^2), k\geq 1, f(0) = 0, Df(0)=0$.
>
> Consider the following system :
>   $$x'=f_1(x,y)$$
>   $$y' = -y + f_2(x,y)$$
>
> which can be translated to :
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}'= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} + f(x,y)$$
>
> Observe that the linearized system has an eigenvalue equal to zero and that the critical point $O(0,0)$ is non-hyperbolic.
>
> Solving the system of equations : 
>   $$\begin{cases} -y(x) + f_2(x,y(x)) = 0 \\ y(0) = y'(0) = 0 \end{cases}$$
>
> the function $y(x)$ can be expressed in terms of $x$.
>
> Finally : 
>   $$f_1(x,y(x))=ax^k+O(|x|^{k+1})$$
>   which leads to the origin $O(0,0)$ being asymptotically stable if $a<0$ and $k$ odd, else it's unstable.

**Attempt/Discussion :**

I'll let :

$$f_1(x,y) = -x^2 + 2xy$$
$$f_2(x,y) = y^2 + xy$$

since having $-2$ instead of $-1$ at my system's matrix will not change anything (just a multiplication constant).

Then, it's indeed easy to see that the matrix of the linearized system at the origin describes a non-hyperbolic critical point, as :

$$\det(J(0,0)) = 0$$

and that we have a zero eigenvalue, since $\det(J(0,0)-λI)=0$ yields a solution $λ=0$ (where $J(0,0)$ is the Jacobian at $(0,0)$).

Solving now :

$$-2y(x) + f_2(x,y(x)) = 0 \Rightarrow -2y(x) + y^2(x) + xy(x) = 0 \Rightarrow y^2(x) + (x-2)y(x) = 0 \Rightarrow y(x)[y(x) + x-2] = 0$$

which means that $y(x)=0$ or that $y(x) = 2-x$.

Now, I guess I'll have to check both cases, which means that at first :

$$f_1(x,y(x)=0) = -x^2$$

which, according to the theorem, yields that the origin $O(0,0)$ is unstable.

Checking for the other case :

$$f_1(x,y(x)=2-x)=-(2-x)^2 + 2x(2-x)=-4 + 4x - x^2 + 4x - 2x^2$$ 
$$=$$
$$-3x^2 + 8x - 4$$

Now, again, the power of $x$ is not odd so it means automatically that the origin is unstable ? Questioning this though, since the form is not the one reported by the theorem. What does the notation $O(|x|^{k+1})$ specifically refers too in such example ?

Also, wanted to ask, is my approach correct ? It seems that this is **the only** theorem-method we have been taught/expected to study for systems with an eigenvalue being zero, but I found a hard time applying it to more complicated systems (let's say with constants and higher powers).

Comment: I guess the person that downvoted instantly when the question was posted (20 seconds later) must have really went through it.

Comment: The second case is not relevant as $y(x)=2-x$ is not of the form $O(x^k)$ with a positive $k$, i.e., $y(0)=2\ne 0$ does not cross $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Also, $f_1(x,2-x)=-x^2+2x(2-x)=4x-3x^2$. Which means that $(x,y)=(0,2)$ is also unstable?

Comment: @LutzL Thanks a lot for your comments, it seems that I have misunderstood something. First of all, what does the term $O(x^k)$ denote in such case ? Secondly, is it safe to say that $(0,0)$ is unstable since it holds for $y(x)=0$ as shown above ? How would I need to proceed in a different case?

Comment: Here, $g(x)=O(x^k)$ can be interpreted as that there is some continuous function $r$ so that $g(x)=x^kr(x)$. And yes, the first part looks OK.

Comment: @LutzL Understood, thanks a lot ! So, after all this seems like a rather complicated method/theorem, as it depends on a lot of stuff. How would one proceed for the case of $y(x) = 2-x$ though ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WolframAlpha with the stream plot command produces the following phase portraît

[image]

At $(0,0)$ you found that $y$ is smaller than any power of $x$, the local approximation is given by $\dot x=-x^2$ so that $$x(t)=\frac{x_0}{1+x_0t}$$ and then (again disregarding higher order terms in $y$) $\dot y/y=-2+x$ so that $\ln(y/y_0)=-2t+\ln(1+x_0t)$ or
$$
y(t)=y_0e^{-2t}(1+x_0t).
$$
This contrast of exponential reduction in $y$ against hyperbolic reduction in $x$ for $x_0>0$ resp. hyperbolic divergence for $x_0<0$ can be seen in the magnification below.

[image]

For the stationary point $(0,2)$ one can write the system as
\begin{alignat}{2}
\dot x &=4x&&-x^2+2x(y-2)\\
\dot y &=2x+2(y-2)&&+(y-2)^2+2x(y-2)
\end{alignat}
which clearly is in the first order approximation an unstable point, as can also be seen in the magnification.

[image]

Comment: Really great answer (and help on the comments which was important too). It's worth mentioning that out of the solutions of $-y(x) + f_2(x,y)$ one must keep the **correct** one for the stationary point wanted. Thanks !