# Stability of system of parameters $\kappa, \lambda$ when there is a zero eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

**Exercise :**

> Consider the following system of differential equations that is dependent by two parameters $κ$ and $λ$ :
>   $$x'=-x^3-κxy^3 + xy$$
>   $$y'=-y+yx^2-x^2+λ$$
>   Find the curve of the branch around the origin of the $(κ,λ)$ space for stationary points around $O(0,0)$. Moreover draw phase portraits for every area of the parameter space $(κ,λ)$

**Discussion/Question :**

This is an exercise under the title **Zero Eigenvalue : Stability and Branches**. I know how to work around systems with a zero eigenvalue and non-hyperbolic stationary point as described in another question of mind, [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602976/stability-of-differential-system-when-eigenvalue-is-zero)

In this case though, things get a little complicated since the stationary point isn't the origin $O(0,0)$. As one can see easily, a stationary point is $(0,λ)$.

My first question is exactly the first part of the exercise : **How would one find the branch curve around the origin of $(κ,λ)$** ? I know how to find a branch point in a $1\times 1$ system but not in higher dimensions. Also, what does the phrase : **origin of $(κ,λ)$ space** mean ? Does it mean the space generated by a $2 \times 2$ vector as $\text{span}[(κ,λ)]$ ?

My second question is : **The phrase "around $(0,0)$ seems too broad. Is $(0,λ)$ considered "around" $(0,0)$ for $ λ << 1$ ?** Finally, how would one draw phase portraits with respect to a space that yields infinite pairs ?

**I would really appreciate if someone could elaborate thoroughly on how to proceed on such a problem, as I'm trying to cover every possible exercise for my upcoming term exams in 9 days.**

Comment: For $(\kappa, \lambda) = (0, 0)$ there is an equilibrium at the $(x, y) = (0, 0)$. If you slightly change $(\kappa, \lambda)$, then position and existence and number of equilibria will change too. "Around" means that $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are small. In practice that sometimes means that if you have some smooth curve that describes, for example, parameter values for which there is a single equilibrium near $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ then you should find first one or two terms of Taylor expansion for this curve.

Comment: For example, if you want to find equilibria which have exactly one zero eigenvalue, you have a system $P(x, y, \kappa, \lambda) = 0,\, Q(x, y, \kappa, \lambda) = 0$ (equilibrium condition) plus ${\rm det}\, J(x, y, \kappa, \lambda) = 0$ (degeneracy condition). Four variables, three equations; if some conditions are met, this defines a curve in $(x, y, \kappa, \lambda)$ space. This is a kind of branch curve.

Comment: @Evgeny Hello, thanks a lot for your comments ! I was away most of the day so I just had the chance to check. As $J(...)$ you denote the Jacobian matrix aka the linearization matrix ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Since $(\kappa, \lambda) = (0, 0)$ might be a point of regular saddle-node bifurcation locally the branching curve separates the domain with no equilibria and domain with two equilibria.